# How to number files on github so that they occur in sequence?

Tags: github, numbers

When I try to upload my folder to github the numbering goes like :
10 comes straight after 1 but I want normal numbering like 1 , 2, 3 and so on ... Can you tell me how to number the files so that it occurs normally ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an underscore (or some character) at the beginning. That works in NTFS.